# How to count the occurrence of an element in a nested Map in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, hashmap

I want to find an efficient way to count the occurrences of an element in a list located in a two level map.

The inner maps might have non-unique keys among them, for example `deep1` exists in `shallow1` an `shallow2`. There could be non-unique values across vectors. For example `1` occurs in `shallow1 -> deep1` and `shallow2 -> deep1` but each vector itself does not have duplicate values.

For example, for the following map,

```
val twoLevelMap: Map[String, Map[String, Vector[Int]]] = Map(
  "shallow1" -> Map(
    "deep1" -> Vector(1, 3, 7),
    "deep2" -> Vector(3, 8)),
  "shallow2" -> Map(
    "deep1" -> Vector(1, 2),
    "deep4" -> Vector(7, 8, 9)))
```

I expect to get

> Map(1 -> 2,   2 -> 1,   3 -> 2,   7 -> 2,   8 -> 2,   9 -> 1)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for `2.13` which is as generic *(and efficient)* as possible.
*(You can easily adapt this to work on `2.12` by changing `updatedWith` and `IterableOnce`)*.

```
def countInnerValues[T, C[x] <: IterableOnce[x]](nestedMap: Map[String, Map[String, C[T]]]): Map[T, Int] = {
  val iterator = for {
    innerMaps <- nestedMap.valuesIterator
    innerValues <- innerMaps.valuesIterator
    value <- innerValues.iterator
  } yield value


  iterator.foldLeft(Map.empty[T, Int]) { (acc, t) =>
    acc.updatedWith(key = t) {
      case Some(count) => Some(count + 1)
      case None        => Some(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @smaug something like `acc.get(key = t) match { case Some(count) => acc + (t -> (count + 1))  case None => acc + (t -> 1) }`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this

```
twoLevelMap.flatMap(_._2.values).flatten.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

Which produces the expected output :

> Map(1 -> 2, 9 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 7 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 8 -> 2)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach by flattening the nested Map values, followed by a `groupMapReduce`:

```
twoLevelMap.flatMap(_._2.values).flatten.
  groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] =
//   HashMap(1 -> 2, 9 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 7 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 8 -> 2)
```

Note that `groupMapReduce` requires Scala 2.13+.